# We need a minecraft trouble shooting tag because it has a large portion of questions

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

Do we need a Minecraft trouble shooting tag because it has a large portion of questions? Recently I have seen that a lot of the questions are about Minecraft problems. Now I know they have 2 tags, both Minecraft and technical support, but new users only put one of them. I think if we put them together than users who have found solutions to one problem can subscribe/follow/etc. the tag and they can share their knowledge better.

Comment: Minecraft questions tend to be a large portion of our moderation efforts. The bar for moderation for them is a lot lower than most questions, due to both their quantity, and quality (or lack thereof).

Comment: @Frank Just to be clear, you are talking about technical issues questions. If not, then I resent you and your statement's premise as a silver badge in the tag.

Comment: @Unionhawk, not entirey. I see a lot of "I want to do this how do I do it" questions for minecraft where the user has not done any research effort at all, and simply wants Arqade to write out the code or tell them how its done. I see these closed regularly, often as duplicates.

Comment: @Timelord64 that often avoids XY problems but I am not going to have that discussion today, I'm too sick to deal with that argument. But I do appreciate you generalizing the entire tag.

Comment: @Unionhawk, there is obviously more general issues with technical support questions in regards to Minecraft. If there wasn't, we would argue that ALL technical support for ALL modded games is off topic, and yet, **we only appear to close the Minecraft-related questions**. I think the issue isnt a generalisation of Minecraft users, but there is easily a lot more questions being asked about minecraft then most other games. The more questions there are, the more undesirable questions there will be.

Comment: @Timelord64 You're right, it isn't a generalization if it also happens to be a pattern. I forgot. And many people *do* argue that the fact that modded minecraft tech support is particularly off-topic is problematic. I happen to be one of those people.

Answer (score 11):

**No**. The [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag exists, and should be used in these cases. There is no reason to have a specific tag for this.

Comment: To add to this answer: if you do see a 'technical issue' Minecraft question that doesn't have that tag, be sure to add it! :-). It's up to the entire community as a whole to make sure questions are appropriately tagged :-)

Comment: @Robotnik I have seen multiple edits by this question's OP where they edit in the [technical-issues] tag but fail to fix the numerous other obvious problems with the question. So basically, make sure you fix *all* problems with the question, not just the tag.

Comment: @angussidney - of course, I should've mentioned that :-)